# SHIFT+F10 while repairing Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-pe

When you repair Windows XP if you press **SHIFT+F10** while **Installing Devices** is displayed on the screen it will take you to the Control Panel, where you can easily reconfigure the system. Is it a loophole or Windows developers intentionally did this for some purpose.
I have tried this using Virtual PC and it works with SP1 and SP2.
How do people find these sort of things? I mean how will anyone know which key to press to break into the system? I am not a hacker, just a normal user. I read it somewhere and tried. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design for troubleshooting and other purposes. For some it is a way to play solitaire during the install process after the exe is copied.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/242380

(Edit) Also look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295116 for info on XP

Comment: AKA the $100 XP Trick

http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies.cfm?t=498320&p=6

Comment: Windows Microsoft XP is not listed in the **Applies to** list.

Comment: While XP might not be listed this is the article that explains the purpose to Shift+F10. Here is a link that applies to XP and mentions to functionality http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295116

Answer (score 0):

Shift+F10 can also be used to reset account passwords if they are forgotten, see the second technique.

http://www.clazh.com/recover-lost-forgotten-windows-xp-administrator-password/